A Problem using Limits of Sequences of Functions
Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of nonnegative extended real-valued functions on $X$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$. Take a simple function $0\leq\varphi\leq f$. If $X_{\infty}=\{x\in X: \varphi(x)=a>0\}$ and $A_n=\{x\in X: f_k(x)\geq \frac{a}{2} ~\text{for all}~ k\geq n\}$. Show that $X_{\infty}\subseteq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n$.
I know that if $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n=f<\infty$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{a}{2}$, so for all $x\in X$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n\geq N$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
   |f_n(x)-f(x)|&<&\frac{a}{2}\\
   -\frac{a}{2}<f_n(x)-f(x)&<&\frac{a}{2}\\
   \implies f_n(x)&>&f(x)-\frac{a}{2}\\
  \end{eqnarray*}
Hence for any $x\in X_\infty$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
   f_n(x)&>&f(x)-\frac{a}{2}\\
   &\geq&\varphi(x)-\frac{a}{2}~~~~\text{since $\varphi\leq f$ on $X$}\\
   &=&a-\frac{a}{2}\\
   &=&\frac{a}{2}
  \end{eqnarray*}
implying $x\in A_N$, Therefore, $X_\infty\subseteq \displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n.$
If the limit is infinity, I used this definition provided in the internet "Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions with common domain $X$, $f$ be a function on $X$, and $A\subset X$. We say that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $\infty$ on $A$ if $\forall x\in A$ and $\forall c\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$ we have that $f_n(x)\geq c$. We call $\infty$ the limit of $\{f_n\}$ and write $\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n=\infty$."
Following this, I will get the result however, I cant find any book that states this one (it has to be a book), and I am having a hard time proving it without considering cases (a proof that would be true regardless). Is there other way to prove this one?

Since ${f_n}$ is a sequence of extend real-valued functions, the limit could be infinite. Why is the statement true only for a finite limit?

If you do mind me asking, why is $\varphi(x)=f(x)=a=\infty$?

but you cannot just equate $f(x)$ to $a$ because $f(x)$ is assumed to be the limit of $f_n$, right? and you cannot assume $\varphi(x)=f(x)$ because like that $f(x)$ could be infinite and $\varphi(x)$ is a real-value, its a simple function.

Sorry for having misunderstood your question. I deleted my comments.

Your problem is not really about functions. Given $x\in X$ (temporarily fixed), let $y_n:=f_n(x),y:=f(x)\in\overline{\Bbb R}$ and assume $$b<y=\lim y_n.$$ What you want to prove "without considering cases" $(y<\infty,y=\infty)$ is: $$\exists n\in\Bbb N\quad\forall k\ge n\quad y_k\ge b.$$ This can be derived from the following uniform definition of limits of sequences in $\overline{\Bbb R}$: $y=\lim y_n$ iff $$\forall V\in\mathcal V(y)\quad\exists n\in\Bbb N\quad\forall k\ge n\quad y_k\in V,$$
where $V\in\mathcal V(y)$ means $V$ is a neighborhood of $y$, i.e. $V$ contains some interval $(u,v)$ or $[-\infty, v)$ or $(u, \infty]$ containing $y$.
